# Serial Monitor Just Stops Working

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, communication

I am communicating with two Arduinos with serial. The program works great for a while but then the serial monitor stops showing values in the RX code and will not work again unless the code is uploaded again. Why is this happening?

TX code:

```cpp
/*
  Transmitting Code
  Reads potentiometers and sends them through serial
*/

int data [12];     // to send bytes
int start [2];

int Pin1A = A0;  
int Joystick1A;  //crab

int Pin1B = A1;
int Joystick1B;  //up down

int Pin2A = A2;
int Joystick2A;   // pitch

int Pin2B = A3;  
int Joystick2B;  // up down

int Pin3A = A4;   // yaw r-l
int Joystick3A;

int Pin3B = A5;
int Joystick3B;   // forward-back

unsigned char checksum0;
unsigned char checksum1;
unsigned char checksum2;
unsigned char checksum3;
unsigned char checksum4;
unsigned char checksum5;
unsigned char handshake;
unsigned char handshake2;
unsigned char handshake3;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(4800);
  Serial1.begin(4800);
  pinMode(19, INPUT);
  pinMode(18, OUTPUT);
}


void loop() {

// READ THE POTENTIOMETERS:

  Joystick1A = analogRead(Pin1A);   // reads the value of the potentiometer (Joystick1Aue between 0 and 1023)
  data[0] = Joystick1A & 0xFF; //least significant 8 bit byte
  data[1] = (Joystick1A >> 8); //most significant 2 bits

  Joystick1B = analogRead(Pin1B);
  data[2] = Joystick1B & 0xFF;
  data[3] = (Joystick1B >> 8);

  Joystick2A = analogRead(Pin2A);
  data[4] = Joystick2A & 0xFF;
  data[5] = (Joystick2A >> 8);

  Joystick2B = analogRead(Pin2B);   // reads the value of the potentiometer (Joystick1Aue between 0 and 1023)
  data[6] = Joystick2B & 0xFF; //least significant 8 bit byte
  data[7] = (Joystick2B >> 8); //most significant 2 bits

  Joystick3A = analogRead(Pin3A);
  data[8] = Joystick3A & 0xFF;
  data[9] = (Joystick3A >> 8);

  Joystick3B = analogRead(Pin3B);
  data[10] = Joystick3B & 0xFF;
  data[11] = (Joystick3B >> 8);

// CREATE CHECKSUMS:

  checksum0 = ~(data[0]+data[1]) + 1;

  checksum1 = ~(data[2]+data[3]) + 1;

  checksum2 = ~(data[4]+data[5]) + 1;

  checksum3 = ~(data[6]+data[7]) + 1;

  checksum4 = ~(data[8]+data[9]) + 1;

  checksum5 = ~(data[10]+data[11]) + 1;
// WRITE VALUES AND CHECKSUMS TO SERIAL:

while (Serial1.available()<3) { 
  ; //wait for request from receiver
}
  handshake = Serial1.read();
  handshake2 = Serial1.read(); 
  handshake3 = Serial1.read();

  if ((handshake == 1) && (handshake2 == 2) && (handshake3 == 3)) {

Serial1.write(1);

  Serial1.write(data[0]); 
  Serial1.write(data[1]); 
    Serial1.write(checksum0);

  Serial1.write(data[2]);
  Serial1.write(data[3]); //bytes sent
    Serial1.write(checksum1);

  Serial1.write(data[4]);
  Serial1.write(data[5]);
    Serial1.write(checksum2);

  Serial1.write(data[6]); 
  Serial1.write(data[7]); 
    Serial1.write(checksum3);

  Serial1.write(data[8]);
  Serial1.write(data[9]); //bytes sent
    Serial1.write(checksum4);

  Serial1.write(data[10]);
  Serial1.write(data[11]);
    Serial1.write(checksum5);

Serial1.write(2);

   delay(10);     // delay in between reads for stability
  }

// VIEW IN SERIAL MONTIOR:

}
```

RX code:

```cpp
/*
  Receving Code
  Reads bytes from Transmitting Code and put thems back together
  Applies the read bytes to our motor control board
*/

unsigned char val[12];    // variable to read the value from the analog pin
int Joystick1A;      // 0-1024 received from serial
int Joystick1B;
int Joystick2A;
int Joystick2B;      // 0-1024 received from serial
int Joystick3A;
int Joystick3B;

unsigned char checksum0;
unsigned char checksum1;
unsigned char checksum2;
unsigned char checksum3;
unsigned char checksum4;
unsigned char checksum5;
unsigned char FirstByte;
unsigned char LastByte;

unsigned char checkit0;
unsigned char checkit1;
unsigned char checkit2;
unsigned char checkit3;
unsigned char checkit4;
unsigned char checkit5;

//ALL MOTORS:
int V1Direction = 31;
int V1PWM = 2;     //MOTOR V1 
int V1Motor;

int V2Direction = 33;
int V2PWM = 3;     //MOTOR V2
int V2Motor;

int V3Direction = 35;
int V3PWM = 4;     //MOTOR V3
int V3Motor;

int V4Direction = 37;
int V4PWM = 5;     //MOTOR V4
int V4Motor;

int H1Direction = 39;
int H1PWM = 6;     //MOTOR H1
int H1Motor;

int H2Direction = 41;
int H2PWM = 7;     //MOTOR H2
int H2Motor;

int H3Direction = 43;
int H3PWM = 8;     //MOTOR H3
int H3Motor;

int H4Direction = 45;
int H4PWM = 9;     //MOTOR H4
int H4Motor;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(4800);
  Serial1.begin(4800);
//  Serial1.begin(4800); 
  pinMode(10, INPUT);
  pinMode(18, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {

  Serial1.write(1);
  Serial1.write(2);
  Serial1.write(3);

  if (Serial1.available()>18) {  

  FirstByte=Serial1.read();

  if (FirstByte == 1) {
    val[0]=Serial1.read();         // least significant 8 bits
    val[1]=Serial1.read();         // most significant 2 bits   
     checksum0=Serial1.read();     // checksum

    val[2]=Serial1.read();
    val[3]=Serial1.read();
     checksum1=Serial1.read();

    val[4]=Serial1.read();
    val[5]=Serial1.read(); 
     checksum2=Serial1.read();

    val[6]=Serial1.read();         // least significant 8 bits
    val[7]=Serial1.read();         // most significant 2 bits   
     checksum3=Serial1.read();     // checksum

    val[8]=Serial1.read();
    val[9]=Serial1.read();
     checksum4=Serial1.read();

    val[10]=Serial1.read();
    val[11]=Serial1.read(); 
     checksum5=Serial1.read();

   LastByte = Serial1.read();

// get the checksum last

    checkit0 = val[0]+val[1]+checksum0;
    checkit1 = val[2]+val[3]+checksum1;
    checkit2 = val[4]+val[5]+checksum2; 
    checkit3 = val[6]+val[7]+checksum3;
    checkit4 = val[8]+val[9]+checksum4;
    checkit5 = val[10]+val[11]+checksum5; 

if (LastByte == 2) {
  if (checkit0==0)  {
    Joystick1A = val[1]<<8 | val[0]; }

  if (checkit1==0)  {
    Joystick1B = val[3]<<8 | val[2]; }

  if (checkit2==0)  {
    Joystick2A = val[5]<<8 | val[4]; }

  if (checkit3==0)  {
    Joystick2B = val[7]<<8 | val[6]; }

  if (checkit4==0)  {
    Joystick3A = val[9]<<8 | val[8]; }

  if (checkit5==0)  {
    Joystick3B = val[11]<<8 | val[10]; }

}
else (Serial.println("Goodbye"));
    Serial.print(Joystick1A);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(Joystick1B);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(Joystick2A);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(Joystick2B);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(Joystick3A);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.println(Joystick3B);
    delay(10);

  }
  }
  }
```

Comment: Please edit question and tell what happens in the following cases: (a) restart serial monitor (ie exit from it then restart it; (b) push reset button on the Mega; (c) replug USB cables (ie unplug them and then plug in again).  Also, please edit question and indicate whether you are referring to serial communications via USB link, whether each Arduino is plugged into a USB port, etc.

Comment: And when does it stop? Is it always at the end of a cycle, or is it at a random point half way through? Also, how long does it work for before it fails - is it the same each time?

Comment: You might want to think about refactoring you code by using loops it will make it easier to track down the fault.